# ScrollView working on Virtual Device but not on Mobile Device

Tags: android, mobile, scrollview

My code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#f8f9fe">

<include layout="@layout/actionbar_layout"/>
<LinearLayout 
    android:layout_width="match_parent" 
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2" 
    android:weightSum="1" 
    android:background="#4A0025" 
    android:layout_height="28dp">
    <TextView 
        android:layout_width="180dp" 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="NAME" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:paddingTop="5dp" 
        android:id="@+id/month" 
        android:layout_weight="0.48" 
        android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
        android:textColor="#FFF"></TextView>
    <TextView android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:text="TYPE" 
        android:layout_gravity="center" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:paddingTop="5dp" 
        android:id="@+id/year" 
        android:layout_weight="0.36" 
        android:textColor="#FFF"></TextView>
    <TextView 
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
        android:text="STATUS" 
        android:layout_gravity="right" 
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" 
        android:paddingTop="5dp" 
        android:id="@+id/amount" 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
        android:textColor="#FFF"></TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>


<LinearLayout 
  android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
      android:layout_width="match_parent" 
      android:id="@+id/linearLayout3" 
      android:weightSum="1">

    <TextView 
           android:layout_width="180dp" 
           android:text="Textview 1" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:id="@+id/N1" 
           android:paddingBottom="5dp" 
           android:paddingRight="5dp" 
           android:paddingTop="5dp" 
           android:layout_gravity="left" 
           android:layout_weight="0.32" 
           android:gravity="left|center" 
           android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
           android:textColor="#ab330b"></TextView>
    <TextView 
           android:layout_width="wrap_content" 
           android:text="Textview 2" 
           android:layout_height="wrap_content" 
           android:id="@+id/N2" 
           android:paddingBottom="5dp" 
           android:paddingRight="5dp" 
           android:paddingTop="5dp" 
           android:layout_gravity="left" 
           android:layout_weight="0.32" 
           android:gravity="left|center" 
           android:paddingLeft="10dp" 
           android:textColor="#ab330b"></TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

     <include layout="@layout/footer_layout"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

I edit again, my list view work, but Textview 1 and Textview 2 not show. 
I want Textview 1 and Textview 2 below my listview

when i add scrollview, working on Virtual Device but not on Mobile Device.
But when I not use scrollview my footer layout do not show

Comment: remove  `ScrollView `

Comment: it work. but my footer missing. and if I add textview after listview, text and footer missing.

Answer (score 0):

Just try this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="#f8f9fe" >

<include
    android:id="@+id/top_header"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    layout="@layout/actionbar_layout" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="28dp"
    android:layout_below="@+id/top_header"
    android:background="#4A0025"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/month"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.48"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="NAME"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/year"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center"
        android:layout_weight="0.36"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="TYPE"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/amount"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="STATUS"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall"
        android:textColor="#FFF" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@+id/linearLayout2"
    android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout3" />

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_above="@+id/include1"
    android:weightSum="1" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/N1"
        android:layout_width="180dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.32"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Textview 1"
        android:textColor="#ab330b" >
    </TextView>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/N2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="left"
        android:layout_weight="0.32"
        android:gravity="left|center"
        android:paddingBottom="5dp"
        android:paddingLeft="10dp"
        android:paddingRight="5dp"
        android:paddingTop="5dp"
        android:text="Textview 2"
        android:textColor="#ab330b" >
    </TextView>
</LinearLayout>

<include
    android:id="@+id/include1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    layout="@layout/footer_layout" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: it works.

if I want add a TextView after list and before footer, what should I add.

Comment: not work, app error.

From my app textview above list more important than footer.

Comment: I edited my code, that code work at my app. 
but Textview 1, Textview 2, and footer missing

Comment: error, app close

FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Exception : your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

. But my 1st code works

Comment: @DonyAditya in my answer change android:id="@+id/list" line to android:id="@android:id/list".

Comment: it work...Thank You so much. do you have a blog or web. If I have a problem, I want your help.

Comment: @DonyAditya Welcome.. I didn't have blog or web. If u need any help just post ur question here... Lots of friends will help u including me...